# Get variable from a Numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, indexing, pytorch, torch

For a image classification problem with Pytorch, I read in my data as follows:

```
import scipy .io
emnist = scipy.io.loadmat(DATA_DIR + '/emnist-letters.mat')
data = emnist ['dataset']
X_train = data ['train'][0, 0]['images'][0, 0]
X_train = X_train.reshape((-1,28,28), order='F')

y_train = data ['train'][0, 0]['labels'][0, 0]

X_test = data ['test'][0, 0]['images'][0, 0]
X_test = X_test.reshape((-1,28,28), order = 'F')

y_test = data ['test'][0, 0]['labels'][0, 0]
```

I aim to create a dataset, using:

```
train_dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(X_train), torch.from_numpy(y_train))
```

Currently, when I run an instance of `y_train`, the output is an array:

```
y_train[0]
>>> array([23], dtype=uint8)
```

However, I want `train_dataset` to contain only the number that's inside the array at the 0th index (in this case 23) instead of the entire array.

How can I change my code so that the TensorDataset that is created contains only the first element of the array of `y_train`, instead of the entire array?

Comment: if your data has a dimension of 1 which you want to get rid of, you can use `np.squeeze()`.

Comment: You should clarify whether what @Mehraban has written is what you are after. I understood you want your whole `train_dataset` have only single class (in this case `23`).

Comment: Check the `shape` (and `dtype`) of the arrays that you fetch form the `mat`.  As the indexing that you already do shows, that data can be a complicated nesting of structured arrays, object dtype arrays, and 2d (or higher) arrays.  That's all part of translating MATLAB `struct` and `cell` into `numpy`.

Comment: Thank you, Mehraban's answer worked for me indeed. If you post it as an answer, I will upvote it and mark it as the official answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.squeeze()` to get rid of dimensions of the data with size 1. If you mean to remove a specific dimension, pass it to `squeeze`.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randn(1, 2, 1, 3, 1)
arr.squeeze().shape # (2, 3)

arr.squeeze(2).shape # (1, 2, 3, 1)
```